# make the condition in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, valueerror

could anyone help with this issue ?
I got an error on Python like below of the ss.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a5uX.png)

Here is my code:

```
longitude_list = []
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    if country == "United States":
        longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
        longitude_list.append(longitude)
        median = np.median(longitude_list)

for i in range(2, maxRow+1):
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    if country == "United States":
        if median.any() > longitude_list:
            if pdsCnt[2] < allocation:
                sheet.cell(i,25).value = pds[2]
                pdsCnt[2]+=1
            else:
                pdsCnt[3] < allocation
                sheet.cell(i,25).value = pds[3]
                pdsCnt[3]+=1    
print(median)
```

I just wanted to make the condition with this 'if median.any() > longitude_list:' however, it returns the error.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this if-statement? You are using the median of longitude_list and check if it is smaller than the longitude_list? What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Is this a LibreOffice Calc macro?  If so, a sample spreadsheet would be helpful in getting this to work.

Comment: Other could give more useful answer, if you clarify what you want to do behinds the code, especially the condition statement.

Comment: [Please don't post error messages as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3104399). Instead, edit your answer to include the error message as quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that median is not a list, so it has not any method called any(). I guess you want the condition to return true if the median is greater than any value of the list, so it should be

```
if median > any(longitude_list):
```

Answer (score 0):

type of `median` is 'numpy.float64', `median.any()` is 'bool',  `longitude_list` is 'list'. comparison between 'bool' and 'list' does not make sense.

As you didn't mention your wanted logic, so I can just guess:

1. You used a second `for` loop, so you want individual 'longitude' not 'longitude_list'.
2. You used `any`, so you want a 'median list'

If above is true, you need to define a 'median list'( let's call it 'median_list'), and append each median into it.

Then the statement could be `if any(median > longitude for median in median_list):`

BTW, your statement `pdsCnt[3] < allocation` does not change the result or the data, so it sounds OK to remove it.

---

According to your comment, following code might work. As I don't know the logic of `allocation`, so I delete it from the condition. If it matters, you can add it back or adjust.

```py
longitude_list = []
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    if country == "United States":
        longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
        longitude_list.append(longitude)

median = np.median(longitude_list)

for i in range(2, maxRow+1):
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    if country == "United States":
        longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
        if longitude > median:
            sheet.cell(i,25).value = pds[2]
            pdsCnt[2]+=1
        else:
            sheet.cell(i,25).value = pds[3]
            pdsCnt[3]+=1
```

Comment: Hi Yang Liu, Thank you for your supporting :) BTW, I actually would like to allocate the longitude to 'pdsCnt[2]' and pdsCnt[3] once I find the median number. So for example, if median would be 90.xxx in longitude, the above of 90 would allocate to pdsCnt[2] and another are allocate to pdsCnt[3]. So if I would like to do that, how I should write the code ?

Comment: You are welcome, Lee. I guess you mean count longitude to 'pdsCnt[2]'. Code added in the answer. You might still need to adjust the code, as the logic is not fully clear. BTW, suggest to add some print statement to debug if you encounter problem.